# Issue with SQL query returning X rows join on number utility table or count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi I have this table: (productid, quantity)

- product a, 10 times
- product b, 15 times
- etc.

and I have this table (productstock) with the fields:

- productstockid
- productid
- etc.

I have to delete product a 10 times from the productstock table. So I decided to make a select query first to see if I can select the correct number of rows of productstock table. In my previous example, I should have a dataset with 25 rows of productstock table. 15 with product b and 10 with product a (order does not matter, because it will be deleted soon) but the thing is that product a might be a 1000 times in productstock table. I only need to remove 10 rows of them.

This is my real query with the real field names etc. I don't mind an answer in pseudo code, as long as it is clear to me what my error is. I also have a utility table called numbers which contains a list of incremental integers. I often use this to inner join and insert products in the productstock.

```
SELECT
    PRODUCTSTOCK.ProductStockId, 
    PRODUCTSTOCK.ProductID, 
    ORDERSPRODUCTS.Amount
FROM PRODUCTSTOCK
INNER JOIN ORDERSPRODUCTS on ORDERSPRODUCTS.ProductID = PRODUCTSTOCK.ProductID 
AND ORDERSPRODUCTS.OrderID = 11706
```

The query from above returns 1000 times product a instead of the 10 times which is in the amount. So I thought to add something like `Having count(productstock) < amount` but that would require me to group by etc. long story short, does not work. Please do not just give me the query, but please tell me what my error is.

**edit** the productid in the ordersproducts table is unique and can be there only once for orderid 11706. So I am looking for something like this:

```
SELECT TOP(ORDERSPRODUCTS.Amount) PRODUCTSTOCK.ProductStockId, PRODUCTSTOCK.ProductID
FROM PRODUCTSTOCK
INNER JOIN ORDERSPRODUCTS on ORDERSPRODUCTS.ProductID = PRODUCTSTOCK.ProductID 
AND ORDERSPRODUCTS.OrderID = 11706
```

but that is a subquery and not allowed.

**edit2** in the real situation, I need to remove 5000+ records from productstock and there are 300+ records in the ordersproducts table for that specific orderid

**edit3** moved the 300+ records to a temp table:

```
select ProductID, Amount into #tmpToDelete
from ORDERSPRODUCTS where OrderID = 11706
```

**edit4** Now I have to execute for every row in `select * from #tmpToDelete`

[image]

```
select top(58) productstock.* from #tmpToDelete 
inner join productstock on #tmpToDelete.productid = productstock.productid
    and productstock.productid = 13502
order by productstock.ProductStockID desc
```

p.s. the screenshot is truncated, there are over 300 records in it.

Comment: Did you try using the `CURSOR` version that I made below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want 10 items from that `SELECT` query, couldn't you use the `TOP` keyword?

```
SELECT TOP 10
    PRODUCTSTOCK.ProductStockId, 
    PRODUCTSTOCK.ProductID, 
    ORDERSPRODUCTS.Amount
FROM PRODUCTSTOCK
INNER JOIN ORDERSPRODUCTS on ORDERSPRODUCTS.ProductID = PRODUCTSTOCK.ProductID 
AND ORDERSPRODUCTS.OrderID = 11706
```

If you need to the 10 value to be variable, it might be an idea to make it dynamic SQL for this part and use a variable (also added you OrderID as a variable):

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR
DECLARE @MyVariable INT
DECLARE @OrderID INT
DECLARE @MySQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @MyVariable = 10
SET @OrderID = 11706

SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT ORDERSPRODUCTS.Amount
FROM PRODUCTSTOCK
INNER JOIN ORDERSPRODUCTS on ORDERSPRODUCTS.ProductID = PRODUCTSTOCK.ProductID 
AND ORDERSPRODUCTS.OrderID = @OrderID

OPEN @MyCursor
FETCH NEXT
FROM @MyCursor INTO @MyVariable
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @MySQL =
    'SELECT TOP ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @MyVariable) + '
        PRODUCTSTOCK.ProductStockId, 
        PRODUCTSTOCK.ProductID, 
        ORDERSPRODUCTS.Amount
    INTO #DeletableData
    FROM PRODUCTSTOCK
    INNER JOIN ORDERSPRODUCTS on ORDERSPRODUCTS.ProductID = PRODUCTSTOCK.ProductID 
    AND ORDERSPRODUCTS.OrderID = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @OrderID) + '

    DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID FROM #DeletableData)'

    EXEC(@MySQL)
END

CLOSE @MyCursor
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor
```

Comment: well product a has 10 in field amount with ordersproducts. so it should be something like top (amount) for each product `select top(ORDERSPRODUCTS.amount) PRODUCTSTOCK.productstockid, PRODUCTSTOCK.ProductID
from PRODUCTSTOCK
inner join ORDERSPRODUCTS on ORDERSPRODUCTS.ProductID = PRODUCTSTOCK.ProductID 
 and ORDERSPRODUCTS.OrderID = 11706`

Comment: Ah, so you in effect need `ORDERSPRODUCTS.Amount` in the `TOP` part of the query, but that comes from the query itself? In that case I would run the query (not in dynamic SQL) to get the amount values, put the code I have above in a `CURSOR`, when you execute the dynamic SQL, put the results into a temporary table so you can access the IDs for you your `DELETE` operation. If that makes sense!

Comment: Something like what I have done there for you, the syntax and variables I have used might be a bit off, but hopefully that will be helpful. If you need more clarification, please ask.